# If I have a dictionary within a dictionary within a list within a dictionary how would I access the info within it?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

So here's the json I have:

```
{
    "hits": [
        {
            "recipe": {
                "url": "www.test.com"
             }
         }
    ]
}
```

How would I access the url value using python so that I can assign "www.test.com" to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Python` use:

```
 url = dic["hits"][0]["recipe"]["url"]
```